# PLSQL: How to do intermediate commit in a stored procedure

Tags: oracle11g

I have a scenario like this:

```
Create Table Tmp_Test(id NUMBER);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Tmp_test_cmt
AS 
BEGIN
  SAVEPOINT A;

      If (Some condition)
       THEN
       INSERT INTO Tmp_Test VALUES(2);
       Other_SP_CALL;
         Commit;
       END IF

     -- Further business logic --
  COMMIT;

  EXCEPTION 
          WHEN OTHER THEN
          ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT A;
END;
```

I am planning to do intermediate commit inside my SP and rollback the whole transition if anything goes wrong otherwise COMMIT the transition finally. But if any of the commit gets hit then i am getting error "ORA-01086: savepoint 'A' never established"

Actually i have prior experience of SQL SERVER where we can use intermediate commit but a single Rollback shall undo all the changes.

I am also planning the same this here in PLSQL that to do intermediate commits and do a complete rollback if something goes wrong. Kindly suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: perhaps try using multiple savepoints instead of committing , and only commit at the end

Comment: What is the benefit of an 'intermediate' commit? You can't roll back past the commit.

Comment: Oracle does not have nested transactions in the way that SQL Server does.  Once you commit, you've committed.  You can't rollback.  What problem are you trying to solve with the intermediate commit?  It appears that you just want to remove that.

Comment: Actually my code handles huge amount of data approx  10 million and I have read in some article that intermediate commit improve performances. Hence trying to implement such scenario. But i have an another question now, if a single commit can not be rolledback then what will happen in case my SP calls an another SP which is implemented with commit then what will happen in case my master SP executes rollback. Will it rollback full transition or shall rollback till the commit statement of called/inner SP

Comment: If it's in the same transaction (which it will be unless it's made an effort to be autonomous) then a commit in the called procedure will commit everything you've done so far. And a rollback is similar. That's why it's considered a bad idea for procedures to do their own transaction control. (Other than via savepoints). [See ACID](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/transact.htm#CNCPT117). And intermediate commits are likely to degrade, not improve, performance. Size your database (undo, temp) big enough to handle the amount of data you have in one go.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alex Poole for your information, could you please help me with some article or resources to learn/understand about handling transitions for large codes.

Comment: See [this AskTom post](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022) for more on why your commit idea was wrong. That also has a brief comment at August 15, 2002 - 7:12 pm UTC about sizing rollback (undo). And more generally, [this DBA answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9773/847) might be helpful if you're used to SQL Server.